# Setting Cookies For Form Autofill

Tags: cookies, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to set cookies on a gravity form submission to collect and store information submitted on one form and fill in the information on another form as well as filling out the original form again if visiting later.

Here is my code which isn't working. I'm setting the cookie based upon the field name and want to later retrieve it with a parameter...

```
add_filter( 'gform_save_field_value', 'save_field_value_email', 10, 4);
function save_field_value_email( $value, $lead, $field, $form ) {
    if ($field['label'] == 'Your Email') {
        setcookie( 'user_email', htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES), time() + 99999999, '/', NULL );
    }

    return $value;
}

add_filter(“gform_field_value_user_email“, “populate_user_email”);
function populate_user_email($value){
    return $_COOKIE[“user_email“];
}
```

I only want this for logged out users...I see that I'm creating a cookie but the value isn't being populated later...also it's changing the email sign to a % sign when I view the cookie content.

Comment: Please refrain from using the comment section to add in more information.  Use the [`edit` button](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/258378/edit) found above or directly underneath your question to append more information. This website functions very differently from a generic forum, please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) to [learn more](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help).